# Uncaught TypeError: Vue.mixin is not a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have installed vue version 2 in my laravel project and have set up everything. but I am experiencing the following error :

**From console :**

```
app.js:2076 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.mixin is not a function
at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:2076:5)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:34977:42)
at app.js:35142:64
at Function.__webpack_require__.O (app.js:35014:23)
at app.js:35144:53
at app.js:35146:12
```

**From gitbash :**

WARNING in export resolveComponent (imported as _resolveComponent) was not found in vue (possible exports: default)

webpack compiled with 8 warnings

**My codes from app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue')
import router from './router'
import vuex from './vuex'
import common from './common'
Vue.mixin(common)

Vue.component('mainapp', require('./app/mainapp.vue').default)
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    router, 
    vuex
})
```

**From routes.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)
import home from './app/website/home.vue'

const routes = [

    {
        path:'/',
        name : '/',
        component: home,
    } 
]

const router = new Router({
    mode:'history',
    routes
}) 

export default router;
```

Comment: You havn't import `Vue` in app.js like you did in routes.js

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js and common.js are on same level ?

Comment: yes, they are in same level

Comment: Can you share your common.js code ?